# What is the mathematical relationship among hyper-parameters alpha, beta, and tau in Alpha neuron of Spiking neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I am recently reading the tutorial on spiking neural networks about Alpha neurons written by [Jason K. Eshraghian](https://www.jasoneshraghian.com/). Here's the [link](https://snntorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial_4.html) to his tutorial. According to his tutorial, the direct implementation is given as:

$U_{\rm mem}(t) = \sum_i W(\epsilon * S_{\rm in})(t)$,

where the kernel $\epsilon$ is an Alpha function given by

$\epsilon(t) = \frac{t}{\tau}e^{1-t/\tau}\Theta(t)$.

$\Theta(t)$ is Heaviside step function. We can see this function is parameterized by $\tau$.

However, in `snntorch`, the above convolution is realized in a recurrent form:

$I_{exc}[t+1]=(\alpha I_{exc}[t]+I_{in}[t+1])-R(\alpha I_{exc}[t]+I_{in}[t+1])$

$I_{inh}[t+1]=(\beta I_{inh}[t]-I_{in}[t+1])-R(\beta I_{inh}[t]-I_{in}[t+1])$

$U[t+1] = \tau_{\alpha}(I_{exc}[t+1]+I_{inh}[t+1])$

Now, the equations are parameterized by $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

So, what is the relationship among $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\tau$?

I have checked the documentation of [`snn.Alpha`](https://snntorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snn.neurons_alpha.html). An equation is given as follows:

$\tau_{\alpha}=\frac{log(\alpha)}{log(\beta)}-log(\alpha)+1$.

But according to my experiment, $\tau_{\alpha}$ does not equal $\tau$.